# How to join two completely different cubes in MDX?

Tags: join, ssrs-2008, ssas, mdx

I want to join two completely different cubes in mdx (I am using MS SSRS 2008). I am really new to mdx and I have no idea how to do it. I want to join by SKU if possible. Can any body please tell me how to do it?

mdx Query 1

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sales], [Measures].[Quantity] } ON COLUMNS, 
        NON EMPTY { ([Date YMD].[Day].ALLMEMBERS * 
                     [Regions And Stores].[Store Name].[Store Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
                     [Products].[Products].ALLMEMBERS * 
                     [SKU].[SKU].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
 FROM [Super] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

mdx Query 2

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Quantity] } ON COLUMNS, 
       NON EMPTY { ([Store Name].[Store Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
                     [Products].[Products].ALLMEMBERS * 
                     [SKU].[SKU].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM [Inventory Activity] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Any help will highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

In SSRS you need to load two Datasets in your report and join them in the tablix. For example:

Load `Dataset1` and `Dataset2` into your report, with the column `ID` which links `Dataset1` to `Dataset2`. Then put a tablix in your report. Display `Dataset1` in your tablix. Now add a new column to your tablix and add the following expression:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Dataset1ID.Value, Fields!Dataset2ID.Value, Fields!SalesAmount.Value, "Dataset2")
```

The expression works as follows:
 - First argument is the foreign key column from `Dataset1`

- Second argument is corrspondending key column from `Dataset2`
- Third argument is the column you want to display in the tablix which is from `Dataset2`
- Forth argument is the name from the dataset you want to join with (`Dataset2`)

Here is the reference for the `Lookup()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I know about the Lookup function. The problem is I am calculating Week on Hand (Inventory) by product and store level. In that case, calculation from two table does not work with lookup function. This where I got stuck and that is why I am trying to make a one table (Sales and Inventory). Hopefully, this will make sense to you. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hey , is there anyway I can create one table with sales and inventory data in tablix?

Comment: If you can link these two fields with a lookup together you can put everything in one table. And its also no probelem to perform some calculations after a lookup. So I dont see why the week calculation shouldnt work

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MDX, I guess you are looking for SQL Join equivalent in MDX. However MDX doesnt support joins like SQL. One way to solve the issue is to retrieve the data via ADOMD into data cells and then join them in memory. However I would like to know the scenario, which requires you to join results from two cubes.

Comment: I am trying to calculate Week on Hand inventory report. They have to build in MS report builder 3.0. This is the one thing that support cubes and I schedule as email.  Anyway, sales data and Inventory data live tow completely different cubes. So I am trying to create a one table.

Comment: @PrasadD the issue here is that your cubes are not designed to support the report you need. You will be better off loading the results of these two MDX queries, either in SQL server temp table or any in memory db, then use SQL to join the data.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. That is why I thought too. I dont think I can do it in side report builder

Comment: @PrasadD You are most welcome. You might want to mark it as answer.